# regex How to remove space bewteen maj character and word

Tags: regex, r

I am working on raw text from OCR processing

```
Antonio G uomez çapateyro
```

I want to remove space between a maj character and an word:

```
Antonio Guomez çapateyro
```

What I tried

```
(?:[A-Z])[\s]

text <- readLines("clipboard" , encoding = "latin1")
text2 <- gsub("(?:[A-Z])[\s]", "", text2)
```

My problem: I can match G with space but I don't know how to remove space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a positive lookbehind to match one or more spaces (`\\s+`) preceded by a capital letter (`(?<=[A-Z])`) and replace it with `''`.

```
gsub("(?<=[A-Z])\\s+", "", str1, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Antonio Guomez çapateyro"
```

Or without any lookaround, we can capture the capital letter as a group followed by one or more spaces and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`).

```
sub("([A-Z])\\s+", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "Antonio Guomez çapateyro"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Antonio G uomez çapateyro"
```

Comment: Working great @akrun